# Error using simulator in Rowley CrossWorks for ARM

Tags: arm, simulator, firmware

I am using Rowley CrossWorks for ARM (v4.9) and the CrossStudio IDE on Windows.  I have built my project and am trying to run it through the ARM simulator.  I can connect to it (Target > Connect > ARM Simulator) successfully; but when I try to run the code, I get the following error:

`Simulator memory write 0x6002b1d0-0x60046407 failed`

I am very new to CrossWorks, so this is probably due to a very basic error on my part.  Does the project need to be created in a special way in order to run it through the simulator?  I have inherited the project from a former colleague and am learning (rapidly) on the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A kind soul answered this for me on the CrossWorks community forum: https://rowley.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/8377524915101/comments/8386007392925.  I needed to set the **Memory Simulation Parameter** property (in Project Properties) to the value *$(MemorySegments)*.